# Arabic text CSV file import?

Tags: r, character-encoding, arabic, csv-import

I can't seem to get to the bottom of this, I want to read a csv file that contains Arabic characters but it's not reading it properly.

this is my sessionInfo

```
R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United    States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3 plyr_1.8.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.2       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.2.4 DBI_0.3.1           tools_3.2.4   
[7] Rcpp_0.12.4
```

I tried this

```
ar <- read.csv (file.choose(),  encoding = "UTF-8")
```

And this

```
ar <- read.csv (file.choose(),  encoding = "Windows-1256")
```

It didn't work out for me, I also tried setting the locale to Arabic but no luck

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Arabic")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the `fileEncoding` argument rather than `encoding`.

Comment: @Thomas I tried UTF-8 fileEncoding, got the same result.

Comment: @Thomas but when I tried Arabic-1256 I got this error: `Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection 'D:\CALL_END_DATA_FEB16_040416.txt'
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'location.txt'`

Comment: i think the last line in your file is not a empty newline

Comment: @chinsoon12 I don't think that's the case because it can read the file in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: @RayanSp Those are warnings, not errors, so the code should have succeeded (though may not look as you intend).

Comment: pls try to do replicate same in python 3 and post the details, R and earlier python versions as issues

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file using `readLines` with the argument `warn = FALSE`, then execute `read.csv` with `text` argument set to the result of `readLines` as below.

**arabic.csv content**:

```
LabelName,Label1,Label2,SpeciesLabel,Group,Subgroup,Species
التسمية 1,Group 1,Subgroup 1,Species 1,1,1,1
التسمية 2,Group 1,Subgroup 1,Species 1,1,1,1
التسمية 3,Group 1,Subgroup 1,Species 1,1,1,1
```

**R code to read csv file**:

```
arabic <- readLines("arabic.csv", warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
Data <- read.csv(text = arabic)
str(Data)
Output:

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ X.U.FEFF.LabelName: Factor w/ 3 levels "التسمية 1","التسمية 2",..: 1 2 3
 $ Label1            : Factor w/ 1 level "Group 1": 1 1 1
 $ Label2            : Factor w/ 1 level "Subgroup 1": 1 1 1
 $ SpeciesLabel      : Factor w/ 1 level "Species 1": 1 1 1
 $ Group             : int  1 1 1
 $ Subgroup          : int  1 1 1
 $ Species           : int  1 1 1
```